# Which impacts will be on Salesforce Marketing Cloud after enabling Person Accounts on Sales Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, person-accounts

I would like to know which impacts, if there are any, on SFMC after enabling the Person Account in Sales Cloud.

I'll explain the requested details:

SALES CLOUD - TO BE: "Person Account" will be enabled . For this reason, the data model will be extended. Business Accounts will be used for B2B while Person Accounts for B2C.

SFMC: AS IS -  At the moment, the journeys, the automations and the email contents (which include amspcript code) are aligned to a previous situation of Person Account's enabling in Sales Cloud.

My questions are:

1) How should we proceed to align SFMC with Sales Cloud with the introduction of the Person Account, in order to avoid problems on automations and journey builder?

2) After enabling Person Account, Is it appropriate to remove contacts from my contact builder and then re-Sync data sources?

3) If I want to inject in the single journey both Person Accounts and Business Accounts, could I use a custom field created on the object Account that is in Lookup(Contact)? I could also make logic with the Person Contact Id, but it does not give me the opportunity to also take the Business Accounts.

Thank you

Comment: The question's a little broad, but one thing to keep in mind is Marketing Cloud doesn't really deal with Accounts. It's only interested in Leads and Contacts as "sendable" objects. You don't inject Accounts (Person or B2B) into Journeys as they're not sendable. You inject the contact records and SFMC doesn't care that much whether they're Person Accounts or not. It's a little confusing for Sales Cloud users used to the mongrel data model of the Person Account being obfuscated. Marketing Cloud still sees what lies behind - Accounts and Contacts.